# How to implement a post process container in one Kubernetes' pod

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I have a golang server which is used to deploy AI model trainings into kubernetes that every training would run their job on a pod. After job is completed, my server need to upload the model output to HDFS/S3.

So I need a post-container to process the upload task like init-container doing init task on k8s pod.

For now, i use a tricky way that adding the model job container into init-containers and running the upload task container in containers. This works if there's no error thrown in init-containers. However, if there's errors in init-conttainer the pod status is `Init:ContainerCannotRun` which should be `Failed` in normal.

I know i can attach a `preStop` command to container lifecycle events if the image container the upload-hdfs/s3 command tool. However I do not want to let the model training images to include these commands. So this is not my answer.

So my question is that how to implement a post process container so that i can run the upload task after job is completed?

I also find a related [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25908) in github, i would try it if there's no other choice.

Comment: Check out Argo: https://github.com/argoproj/argo  It's a framework to create workflows in Kubernetes, with great support for archiving arifacts.

Comment: @IgnacioMillán I know this project, however it's a little heavy to my project currently.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in Kubernetes to cope with it - **preStop hook** and the code which will listen for the **SIGTERM** signal.

Also, you can increase the **termination grace period** to have more time before pod will be terminated.

More information you can find in [Attach Handlers to Container Lifecycle Events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) and [Kubernetes best practices: terminating with grace](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace.html).

Comment: I know preStop hook, but the job containers do not have the hdfs upload command.

Comment: @FeiyuZhou You can add it into container or use container with hadoop pre-installed. Hope following links will help you http://msoliman.me/2017/04/24/hadoop-inside-docker-the-easiest-way-in-5-minutes/  http://bigdatums.net/2017/11/04/creating-hadoop-docker-image/

Comment: I cannot do that because the model training docker images are not owned by me and i also do not want to add this requirment.